# Adding to a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array being returned from the database that looks like so:

```
$data = array(201 => array('description' => blah, 'hours' => 0),
              222 => array('description' => feh, 'hours' => 0);
```

In the next bit of code, I'm using a `foreach` and checking the for the key in another table.  If the next query returns data, I want to update the 'hours' value in that key's array with a new hours value:

```
foreach ($data as $row => $value){
   $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=$row');
   if ($result){
      $value['hours'] = $result['hours'];
   }
```

It's all fine except that I've tried just about every combination of declarations for the foreach loop, but I keep getting the error that the `$value['hours']` is an invalid reference.  I've tried declaring `$value[]` ... but that doesn't work either.  I don't need to iterate through `$value` so another `foreach` loop isn't necessary.

Surely this is easier than my brain is perceiving it.

Here's the whole snippet:

```
foreach($_gspec as $key => $value){

            $sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM List WHERE specialtyID=%s', $key);
            $query = $db->query($sql);

            if ($query->num_rows() !== 0){

                $result = $query->row_array();
                $value['hours'] = $result['hours'];

            }
        }
```

Comment: What are `$result` and `$query` variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want

`$data[$row]['hours'] = $result['hours']`

`$row` would be better named as `$key` (that is what it is!)

Some people would suggest using pointers, but I find this way makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use ampersand in front of the $value in foreach to pass it by reference like this:

```
foreach ($data as $row => &$value){
   $query = $db->query($sql);
   if ($result){
      $value['hours'] = $result['hours'];
   }
}
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

> As of PHP 5, you can easily modify
>   array's elements by preceding $value
>   with &. This will assign reference
>   instead of copying the value.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because that's what I went with for my own sanity, but I gave you an uptick because this works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) ->

```
foreach ($data as $row => & $value) {
   $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=$row');
   // [...]
   if ($result) {
      $value['hours'] = $result['hours'];
   }
}
```